# PyGTK TreeView showing blank rows from ListStore

Tags: python, gtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to show several rows from database in a TreeView but all I am getting are some dummy rows as you can see in the image below.

[image: Application Screenshot]

```
class SettingsDialog(gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Server Settings", self, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT)

        # Instantiate ServerManager
        self.server_manager = ServerManager()

        # Create TreeStore for Server list
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str, str)
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

        # Create TreeViewColumns to display data
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Name")
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        self.treeview.append_column(col)

        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("URL")
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        self.treeview.append_column(col)

        self.vbox.pack_start(self.treeview)

        self.resize(500,350)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.show_all()

        self.load_server_list()


    def load_server_list(self):
        self.liststore.clear()
        servers = self.server_manager.list()
        for name, url in servers.iteritems():
                self.liststore.append([name, url])
        self.show_all()
```

Data returned from `self.server_manager.list()` is valid an added to the list store perfectly. There seems to be something wrong with the `CellRenderers` but I wasn't able to find the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set an attribute mapping on the column. For example, the cellrenderer's *text* attribute value will be displayed in the treeview cell. It is taken from the values on the data model (*self.liststore*). The column number on the model where the value is taken from is specified in the attribute mapping.

```
## Take value for *text* attribute of the cell renderer from the model's 3rd column
col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(title, cellrenderer, text=2)
```